# How to inject HTML (a template) and CSS into a JavaScript file?

Tags: gulp, gulp-inject

I would like a JavaScript file which builds and minifies an HTML and CSS file and pulls them as strings, possibly, so that it can all be one minified JS file to be used.

I'm curious what's the best flow for achieving this. I see that with gulp inject, this may work?

Comment: gulp-inject-stringified-html works great for gulp.  I'm searching for a grunt solution, but have not found one yet.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution: `gulp-js-text-inject` did exactly what I needed here.